# Read more toggle with <br> in text makes the empty space and pull down my "more" button

Tags: html, css

I have created a "read more" toggle with pure css.

I have text in `<p class="read-more-wrap">` and `<span class="read-more-target">`and also using `<ol class="read-more-wrap"> <li class="read-more-target">` for having listed text. But this just give me empty space and pulls my "More" button down. It looks like it has a lot of padding, but does not. 
Also if I apply `<br>` on the next it will pull the "More" button down. This empty space can be seen when the text is hiding. Once I click "More" button the bottom seems to go back to this original spacing.

Can somebody please help me out? I don't want unnecessary large empty space on the top of my "More" button. Please help me.

```css
.the-alternative{
 text-align: left;
 display: inline-block;
 background: rgba(29, 15, 6, 0.9);
 padding: 1em;
}

.taplogo-article{
 display: inline-block;
 float:right;
 margin-top: -4px;
}

.read-more-wrap{
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px; 
}

.read-more-state{
 display:none;
}

.read-more-target{
 opacity: 0;
 max-height: 0;
 font-size: 0;
 transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-wrap .read-more-target {
   opacity: 1;
   font-size: inherit;
   max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
   content: 'More';
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
   content: 'Less';
}

.read-more-trigger {
 margin-top: 40px;
 cursor: pointer;
   display: block;
   padding: 0.3em;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    font-size: .9em;
   line-height: 2;
   border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
   border-radius: .25em;
   margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90px; 
 text-align: center;
}

#ira article {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 border: 1px solid rgba(150,150,150,0.1);
 background-color: rgba(126, 126, 126, 0.6);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#7E7E7E7E', EndColorStr='#7E7E7E7E');
 width: 920px;
 float: right; 
 margin-bottom: 95px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 95px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
}

#ira {
 min-height: 500px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50% 0;
 background-color: #333;
 background-image: url(../images/background9.jpg);
}
```

```html
<section id="ira" class="story" data-speed="16" data-type="background" data-offsetY="250">  
    <div id="wrapper">   
      <article>
       <p class="the-alternative">Website</p>
       <p class="taplogo-article"><img src="images/tapjapanlogo.png" alt="TAP Japan" width="150" height="52" /></p>

      <img src="images/image3.jpg" alt="TAP Japan" width="100%" />
      <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-3" />
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
      <p class="read-more-wrap">  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        <span class="read-more-target">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting.
          <ol class="read-more-wrap"> 
          <li class="read-more-target">Even with access to the Internet and fund databases, many investors in Japan are unsatisfied with the available information.</li>
          <li class="read-more-target">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
          </ol>

          <p class="read-more-wrap"> 
          <span class="read-more-target">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's.</span>
          </p>
        </span>
      </p>
  
  <label for="post-3" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make a quite a few changes in your code to make it work.

- Your html was incorrect and caused a blank paragraph above the button.
- I removed the margins from `.read-more-wrap`.
- I had to add the `read-more-target` class to some of the `read-more-wrap` elements to avoid extra spacing and change the CSS so it applies to them too.
- I replaced your CSS `height` rules with `visibility` which I think is much better.

```css
.the-alternative {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(29, 15, 6, 0.9);
  padding: 1em;
}
.taplogo-article {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -4px;
}
.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}
.read-more-target {
  visibility: collapse;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}
.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-wrap .read-more-target,
.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
}
.read-more-state ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'More';
}
.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Less';
}
.read-more-trigger {
  margin-top: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.3em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 2;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-radius: .25em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: center;
}
#ira article {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.1);
  background-color: rgba(126, 126, 126, 0.6);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#7E7E7E7E', EndColorStr='#7E7E7E7E');
  width: 920px;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 95px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 95px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#ira {
  min-height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 0;
  background-color: #333;
  background-image: url(../images/background9.jpg);
}
```

```html
<section id="ira" class="story" data-speed="16" data-type="background" data-offsetY="250">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <article>
      <p class="the-alternative">Website</p>
      <p class="taplogo-article">
        <img src="images/tapjapanlogo.png" alt="TAP Japan" width="150" height="52" />
      </p>

      <img src="images/image3.jpg" alt="TAP Japan" width="100%" />
      <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-3" />
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
      <p class="read-more-wrap">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        <span class="read-more-target">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting.</span>
      </p>
      <ol class="read-more-wrap read-more-target">
        <li>Even with access to the Internet and fund databases, many investors in Japan are unsatisfied with the available information.</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
      </ol>

      <p class="read-more-wrap read-more-target">
        <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's.</span>
      </p>

      <label for="post-3" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
```